# making you-tube video player in Recycler view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have worked with Youtube Video player inside my activity. Now I have an requirement to place this youtube player in recyclerview adapter.
I have used fragment which uses youtube player class like this

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_holder"
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSu
                                pportFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

but it is making inflate exception.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558818/youtubeplayerfragment-inside-reyclerview). but it is insufficient to understand. Please someone help me.

below is my LogCat result

```
>  Process: com.ensis.recyclerviewwithyoutubeplayer, PID: 12751
                                                                                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                         at com.ensis.recyclerviewwithyoutubeplayer.YoutubeVideoAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(YoutubeVideoAdapter.java:32)
                                                                                         at com.ensis.recyclerviewwithyoutubeplayer.YoutubeVideoAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(YoutubeVideoAdapter.java:15)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6519)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5706)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:610)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3135)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18911)
                                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:676)
                                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:479)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18911)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5995)
                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18911)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5995)
                                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:400)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18911)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5995)
                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18911)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5995)
                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18911)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5995)
                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2662)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18911)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2157)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1261)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6239)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                                     Caused b
```

Comment: Please share your LogCat

Comment: @BekaKK, I removed this code from adapter and placed in MainActivity. Then youtube player is playing videos.

Comment: use adapter and show us your log result

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: post your adapter code also

Comment: it s a basic while I try to run without intialising player in my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in your fragment tag in xml file

```
 android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
```

Comment: does your activity extends YouTubeBaseActivity?

Comment: Maybe it's will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018434/playing-youtube-video-using-recycler-view